# Combine two RegEx?

Tags: regex, expression, qregularexpression

I need to create a regular expression which transforms a path to a cloud solution.

```
\\test.local\testb\test-prozesse\project_prozess\1_Implementierung\2__Datenmigration\1_prozesstest\5_Dokumentation\Dateiname.docx
```

to this:

```
Test-USER>2__Datenmigration>1_prozesstest>5_Dokumentation>Dateiname.docx
```

The first part is to be replaced with the "`Test-USER`"
and the slashes should be replaced with the `>`.

I only managed to delete the first part with this:

```
\\\\[a-zA-Z._]+\\[a-zA-Z._]+\\[a-zA-Z._-]+\\[0-9a-zA-Z._-]+\\[0-9a-zA-Z._-]+\\
```

I use the open source project pathcopycopy and there you have only one line to insert your regular expression

Comment: Then can't you just replace `\\​` with `>`?

Comment: Yes but I need to replace the first part also how do I write that in one line?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I use the open source project pathcopycopy and there you have only one line to insert your regular expression

Comment: Then I don't think there is a way, unless it supports [If-Then-Else Conditionals](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html).

Answer (score -1):

```js
const str = '\\\\test.local\\testb\\test-prozesse\\project_prozess\\1_Implementierung\\2__Datenmigration\\1_prozesstest\\5_Dokumentation\\Dateiname.docx';


const result = str.replace(/^(\\+[^\\]*)(\\+[^\\]*)(\\+[^\\]*)\\?([\w\W]*)$/, function ($0, $1, $2, $3, $4) {   return $4.split('\\').join('>');
})


console.log('result= ', result);
```

Comment: The OP is not using JavaScript

Comment: What's it using?

Comment: Take a look at the comments below the question.